# Input and Output shape mismatched when using binary cross entropy | Keras tf autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm building an autoencoder that takes in 16x16 flattened images and I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (999, 16, 16, 256) was passed for an output of shape (None, 256) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

My Attempt: I thought that I had to reshape the tensors inside the decoder after the `topk` layer but it didn't resolve the error and just outputted more errors. I commented out my attempt below. 
I believe that I need to do some type of reshaping so that the input shape and output shape match each so binary cross entropy loss can work.

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

```
encoding_dim = 16
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16, 16, 256), name ="input")
# flatten your images
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input_img)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(flatten)
encoded2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
# top_k layer
topk = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.top_k(x, k=int(int(x.shape[-1])/2),
                                                sorted=True,
                                                name="topk").values)(encoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(topk) 
decoded2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)
#decoded3 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((16,16,256))(decoded2)
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded2)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', 
                    loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=100,
            batch_size=256,
            shuffle=False,
            validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Comment: Can you post the part where you are computing the loss as well?

Comment: @gorjan Updated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the shape `(999, 16, 16, 256)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your input shape is `(batch, 16, 16, 256)`.

If you want to specify `batch` as `256` explicitly you should use `batch_shape` argument, not `shape` inside your `Input` layer. You shouldn't do that though, as it's better to keep it flexible in case you would like to change it (or batches are of unequal size which is usually the case).

Your output has to be of the same shape, so it should be `keras.layers.Dense(16 * 16, activation="sigmoid")` with `keras.layers.Reshape((16, 16))` at the last output node. Notice you do not specify batch anywhere, only the rest of dimensions.